# Count the rows by group and get the proportion of different columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to find the ratio of CGM prescribed at each location  over number of diabetes patients. my actual data looks like this

| Location | Diabetes present | CGM prescribed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CA | 1 | 1 |
| TX | 1 | 0 |
| TX | 1 | 1 |
| CA | 1 | 0 |
| AZ | 1 | 1 |
| AZ | 1 | 0 |
| AZ | 1 | 1 |
| TX | 1 | 0 |

Desired output:

| location | TotalDiabetes | total CGM | proportion (total cgm/ total diabetes) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CA | 2 | 1 | 0.5 |
| TX | 3 | 1 | 0.33 |
| AZ | 3 | 2 | 0.66 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may get the `sum` of the numeric by 'Location' and then create the proportion column by dividing the Total columns

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   reframe(across(everything(), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
  .names = "Total_{str_remove(.col, ' .*')}"), .by = "Location") %>%
   mutate(proportion = round(Total_CGM/Total_Diabetes, 2))
```

-output

```
  Location Total_Diabetes Total_CGM proportion
1       CA              2         1       0.50
2       TX              3         1       0.33
3       AZ              3         2       0.67
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
transform(aggregate(.~ Location, df1, sum), 
  proportion = round(`CGM prescribed`/`Diabetes present`, 2), 
    check.names = FALSE)
```

-output

```
   Location Diabetes present CGM prescribed proportion
1       AZ                3              2       0.67
2       CA                2              1       0.50
3       TX                3              1       0.33
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Location = c("CA", "TX", "TX", "CA", "AZ", "AZ", 
"AZ", "TX"), `Diabetes present` = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), `CGM prescribed` = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: I added the dplyr package the version is the one that you mentioned but I got an error on function reframe

Comment: @SharonMacwan Do you have version 1.1.0 `reframe` was introduced in that version.  If it is not working, then use `df1 %>% group_by(Location) %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(.x,  na.rm = TRUE), .names = "Total_{str_remove(.col, ' .*')}")) %>%  mutate(proportion = round(Total_CGM/Total_Diabetes, 2))`

Comment: @SharonMacwan I checked it again on a fresh R session.  It gives the same output and my package version is `packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘1.1.0’`

Comment: I am getting the error in across function when I tried to use it through summarise as you suggested  it says must be used inside dplyr verbs.

Comment: @SharonMacwan probably you have loaded `plyr` package which masked the functions.  Can you try on a fresh R session with only dplyr/stirngr loaded

Comment: Yes I can do that I also checked my company blocks some package versions  due to firewall issues so it is not the updated one as told by IT

Comment: @SharonMacwan ok, then the `group_by/summarise` should have worked as that syntax was there for previous many versions

Comment: do I need to use dplyr verb somewhere within the code for the across function to work?

Comment: @SharonMacwan Assuming the `dplyr` is not working, the `base R` updated should  work

Comment: @SharonMacwan `across` I guess got introduced in 1.0.0 or so.  Not sure.  If your version is older than that, it won't work

Comment: makes sense thank you for the update. may be I can just use normal summarise and group by and try to resolve it

Comment: @akrun I tried this ```setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), .(Location), .SDcols = names(df1)[-1]][, pr := `/`(.SD), .(Location), .SDcols = names(df1)[c(3,2)]]``` in data.table but I am getting error with ````/```` as invalid unary operator. I am not sure why is that though since it works with `sum`. Thoughts?

Comment: @M-- I think you need two arguments for the operator. Try with`do.call` or `Reduce` i.e. `setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), .(Location), .SDcols = names(df1)[-1]][, pr := do.call(`/`, .SD), .SDcols = 3:2][]`

Comment: I got it, `/ is not vecotrized!

Comment: I was able to use it with regular summarize and group by function Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution in `data.table`.

```
setnames(setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, sum), .(Location), .SDcols = -1][, 
            proportion := do.call(`/`, .SD), .(Location), .SDcols = 3:2],
         names(df1)[-1], paste0("Total ", sub(" .*", "", names(df1)[-1])))[]

#    Location Total Diabetes Total CGM proportion
# 1:       CA              2         1  0.5000000
# 2:       TX              3         1  0.3333333
# 3:       AZ              3         2  0.6666667
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `dplyr` way:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Location = factor(Location, levels = c("CA", "TX", "AZ"))) %>% 
  group_by(Location) %>% 
  summarise(TotalDiabetes = sum(Diabetes_present),
            Total_CGM = sum(CGM_prescribed),
            Proportion = Total_CGM/TotalDiabetes)
```

```
  Location TotalDiabetes Total_CGM Proportion
  <fct>            <int>     <int>      <dbl>
1 CA                   2         1      0.5  
2 TX                   3         1      0.333
3 AZ                   3         2      0.667
```